# How to split array into equal parts based on values?

Tags: javascript

Input `Arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]`

Expected output:-

`Arr1 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7] = 28`
`Arr2 = [8,9,10] = 27`

The sum of arrays should be almost the same..
It can also be 3 or more parts

How to achieve this via custom function?

```
let Arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
const numberOfParts = 2
function SplitArr(Array, Parts){
   /*  ... */
}
let result = SplitArr(Arr,numberOfParts)
/* result should be [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7],[8,9,10]] */
/* output can be in any format as long as it can get the parts */
```

Comment: What is the criteria for splitting the array? Is it the sum of the values? There's not enough information in the question to provide a good answer.

Comment: @Andy is right, and please provide your own code with details as well.

Comment: Do we have any constraint for the array values like a[i]<10^9 ?

Comment: Loop over the array indexes, using the index as the dividing line between the two parts. Get the sum of each part. Repeat this until the left sum is higher than the right sum.

Comment: Or get the sum of the entire array, then iterate over the array, adding the elements, until they get close to half the sum.

Comment: There's no built-in function for this, you'll have to write code.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can't do that directly by JS functions.
You have to create a custom function to achieve this.

> **I have considered dividing the array into 2 equal parts.**

##### You can't always split the array equally. `Here in this array, you can't partition array into more than 2 subparts, otherwise it will give more than 3 parts as some of the elements are present there having sum more than the partitioned Sum.`

`Note: I treated the array to be sorted, otherwise it depends on the usecase.`

`Note: I have updated the old implementation based on the updated question requirement`

```js
let arr=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]

function splitArrayEqually(arr, parts=2){
  //get the total sum of the array
  let sum = arr.reduce((currentSum, value) => currentSum+value ,0);
  
  //get the half sum of the array
  let partitionedSum = Math.ceil(sum/parts);
  let start=0, end=0, currentSum=0;
  let splittedArray=[];  

  //get the index till which the sum is less then equal partitioned sum
  while(end < arr.length){
    if(currentSum+arr[end] > partitionedSum){
         splittedArray.push(arr.slice(start,end));
         start = end; //start new window from current index
         currentSum = 0; //make sum =0
    }
    //add current end index to sum
    currentSum += arr[end];
    end++;
  }
  splittedArray.push(arr.slice(start));
  return splittedArray;
}

splitted = splitArrayEqually(arr,3);
console.log(splitted)
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let Arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
const numberOfParts = 3

function sumOfArray(arr) {
    if (arr) {
        if (arr.length > 0) {
            let sum = 0
            for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) sum += arr[i]
            return sum
        } else {
            return 0
        }
    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

function SplitArr(Array, Parts) {
    let lastIndex = 0
    let result = []
    function getReamingSum(arr) {
        let psum = sumOfArray(Array.slice(lastIndex)) / Parts
        console.log('psum ' + psum)
        return psum + Parts
    }
    let psum = getReamingSum(Array)
    for (let j = 0; j < Parts; j++) {
        let total = 0
        for (let i = 0; i < Array.length; i++) {
            if (i >= lastIndex) {
                total += Array[i]
                if (total < psum || j === Parts - 1) {
                    if (result[j]?.length > 0) {
                        result[j].push(Array[i])
                    } else {
                        let arr = []
                        arr.push(Array[i])
                        result[j] = arr
                    }
                    lastIndex = i + 1
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result
}
let result = SplitArr(Arr, numberOfParts)
console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the array isn't sorted,using a 2D array, with each sub array with sum almost equal to (sum of array / n).

```
let arr = [9,2,10,4,5,6,7,8,1,3]

arr.sort(function(a, b) { return a - b; });

const sum = arr.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0);

const n = 2; 

const result = [];
let s = 0;
let j = 0;
result[j] = [];
for(let i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
  
  if(s <= Math.floor(sum/n)){

    result[j].push(arr[i]);
    s +=arr[i];
  }
  else{    
    s = 0;
    j = j + 1;   
    result[j] = [];
    result[j].push(arr[i]);
  }
}

console.log(result)
O/P:
[ [1, 2, 3, 4,5, 6, 7], [ 8, 9, 10 ] ]
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10];


const splitArray = (arr,parts) => {
  const totalSum = arr.reduce((acc, item) => {
    acc += item;
    return acc;
  }, 0)
  const splitSum = Math.floor(totalSum / parts);

  const arrObj = arr.reduce((acc, item,index) => {
    acc.sum = acc.sum || 0;
    acc.split = acc.split || {};
    
    const pointer = Math.floor(acc.sum / splitSum);
    //console.log(item,acc.sum, splitSum, pointer);
    acc.split[pointer] = acc.split[pointer] || [];
    acc.split[pointer].push(item);
    acc.splitSum = splitSum;
    acc.sum += item;
    return acc;
  }, {})
  return arrObj;
}

console.log(splitArray(arr,2).split)
```

Answer (score -3):

You're better off making a custom function:

```
let currentTotal = 0
let tempList = []
Arr.forEach(val => {
    if (val >= 27) {
        // push tempList to a new array
        tempList = [];
        currentTotal = val;   
    } else {
        tempList.push(val);
        currentTotal += val;
    }
})
```

Comment: Why are you comparing to `27`?

Comment: That happens to be the dividing point for the example array, it will be different for other arrays.

Comment: And you shouldn't be comparing elements to it, it's the sum of the elements in the subarray.

Comment: If it is a percentage then it would be more appropriate.